# Quality Center - specifying the version in which a test set or a test were executed

Tags: quality-center

My team is part of a project that is practicing the SCRUM methodology. We use continuous integration server to build our product. One of the requirements is to run our integration tests at least once a day on the build that was prepared by the CI server.

Part of our test suite contains a list of business processes we should verify automatically. Our business analysts use QC to manage these requirements.
Therefore, we have prepared a Test Plan and divide it to Test Sets using the Test Lab module. Assuming that my test will be executed on each CI version of the product I would like to specify that the current test was running against some specific product version.

What is the best way to do that in Quality Center?

**Note - we are using Quality Center 11 if that matters.**

Answer (score 2):

If you have administrative access to Quality Center then you can add a custom field in the following location

Customize Project Entities--> Run --> User Field

You can select field type as 'Lookup list' and then select appropriate list in the dropdown below.

Whenever any tester runs any test case, this additional field will be displayed to him and he can select the appropriate release/build version.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is how we do it.  We also assign the field to a list and use the OTA Client to keep the list updated based on our CM data.  Since this is going to be automated it would be a good idea to have QTP automatically insert the build your testing into the field.